# PyCharm PEP8 Code Style highlights not working

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8

I've been having this PEP8 style highlighting issue. The issue is it's not highlighting obvious style issues, like no blank lines before class definitions, or no empty lines at the end of the file. It could have to do with my VM and vagrant, but the project code is hosted locally so I don't think that should be an issue.

If I do `Code > Run Inspection By Name > PEP 8 coding style violation` it says it finds no instances.

Under `File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Python > Blank Lines` I have blank lines set around the class. An oddity is that if I change the number of lines "around method", it changes them in real time in the example text on the right, but it doesn't do the same for lines "around class".

Under `File > Settings > Editor > Inspections > Python` I have "PEP 8 coding style violation" selected. I've tried changing it from warning to error and I still can't see the highlights in my file.

I don't have power saver mode on, which I've learned is a way to deactivate the background style checking in the editor.

I searched in `Help > Show Log in Files` for PEP8 and found "Pep8ExternalAnnotator - Found no suitable interpreter", but I don't know what that means and I couldn't find any references to it online.

I'm running PyCharms professional 2016.3

> PyCharm 2016.3.2
>       Build #PY-163.10154.50, built on December 28, 2016
>       Licensed to arbaerbearfaerfa
>       Subscription is active until October 17, 2017
>       For educational use only.
>       JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 amd64
>       JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Comment: I noticed my PyCharm CE recently updated to the 2017 version. Might be worth updating to see if 2017 exhibits the same behavior for you.

Comment: I updated to the professional edition 2017.1 and the issue persists. I need the PE instead of the CE because I need to use the vagrant plugin or something like that.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Pycharm `2018.3.3`. I'm using the python interpreter on WSL

Answer (score 4):

Here are three more things to check:

- Click the Inspector icon and make sure that you have the [highlighting level set to Inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/accessing-inspection-settings.html).
- There's a second PEP8 inspection, "PEP 8 naming convention violation".
- Ensure that the scope of inspections is set for the entire project.

Comment: I have the highlighting level set to inspections, and the scope is the entire project. I see that second PEP8 inspection, and that one works, but I'm really trying to get the other one to work.

Comment: I'm stumped. Suggest filing a [support request with JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY?q=%23Inspections%20pep8). Bugs with PEP8 inspections have appeared on Windows. You can also submit a private reproducible code sample through their issue tracker.

Comment: thanks, I was about to do that today. I'm on Linux too, Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: How is "Ensure that the scope of inspections is set for the entire project" done?

Comment: @Qaswed https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/inspections-settings.html#5

Comment: @StevePiercy So you mean, that behind the field "Severity", it is selected "In All Scopes"?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issus. In my case I was missing the system interpreter which made all the pep8 not work.  Once added it fixed the issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb8Lf.png)

Answer (score 0):

After I installed Anaconda on Windows 10 (https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/), keeping the box "Register Anaconda as my default Python 3.7" checked, it finnaly worked. I now have two project interpreters and PEP 8 Code Style violations are highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (on mac, python3.8, pycharm v2020.3). I was able to fix it by comparing the `.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml` from a new project with my project that wasnt showing pep8 inspection warnings. The new project had the following line

```
    <inspection_tool class="PyClassicStyleClassInspection" enabled="true" level="WARNING" enabled_by_default="true" />
```

I added this line to my project that wasnt working with pep8 and then it started working immediately. Note: the preferences for the project showed pep8 inspections were enabled, but it just wasnt working.

Answer (score 0):

I have to remove the `venv` folder and add the Python Interpreter again.

Also, I had a problem setting the `venv` folder inside a folder called `src`. When `venv` was on the project's root folder everything worked fine, if I put it in the `src` the PEP8 inspections didn't work. After moving it around and setting the Python Interpreter several times it fixed itself...

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new virtual environment helped my case:

`Settings > Project: XXX > Python Interpreter > Add Interpreter`

Comment: You can comment, you know that, right? This is most definitely not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος It solved the described issue for me. I don't understand how this does't qualify as an answer.

Comment: In any case, even if it qualifies as an answer, you should know this is definitely of the lowest quality type.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος Do you mean because it is short? The thing is though that there is not more to it. I just did that and it solved the issue for me. What should I add to this?

Comment: At least the steps you took to create venv.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος I updated my answer accordingly.